# mysql query to get age 25/04 months format where date format is 1988-04-04?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime-format

I have date field in mysql in 1988-04-04 format.I need to calculate age in 25/04 months format.I tried this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    FLOOR((curdate() - dob) / 31536000),
    'y ',
    FLOOR(MOD((curdate() - dob) / 31536000 * 12, 12)),
    'm'
) `age` from age
```

It is giving me 0/0 months. I'll be grateful for any help.

Comment: First things first, what is 25/04 format? :-) Or is that supposed to be years/month format for an age?

Comment: And, what does 1988-04-04 means. Is it yyyy-mm-dd or yyyy-dd-yy??

Comment: I assume the field 'dob' is within the table 'age'?

Answer (score 1):

When you select `curdate()` in a numeric context, you get the `yyyymmdd` value, such as `20130812` (for today, August 12, 2013). That's not really that useful for date calculations.

By way of example, my birthdate (old fart that I am) would be `19650202`. When you work out the numeric difference between that and today, you get `480610`.

Now, if you divide *that* by `31536000` (not sure where you got that from), you definitiely get zero, despite the fact I'm a 48-year-old geezer :-)

You would be far better off using `datediff()` to work out the number of days difference between two dates and then applying the correct divide and modulo operations to get full-years and months from that, something like (untested but should be a good start):

```
select
    floor (100 * datediff (curdate(), dob) / 36525) as years,
    floor (mod (100 * datediff (curdate(), dob), 36525) / 100 / 30) as months
from age
```

That won't be *perfect* since the location of leap-years will affect it a little, the *actual* days per year is `365.2425` over the long term, and we're assuming exactly `30` days per month but it should be accurate to within a couple of days.

If you want a more accurate measure, you need to find or implement some more exact equations for working out the values.

That's probably going to entail using `year()` and `month()` to extract the relevant fields from both `dob` and the current day and subtracting those, adjusting if if the current date comes before the birthday in the current year.

Answer (score 0):

Using DATEDIFF as suggested by paxdiablo:

```
SELECT
  FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), dob) / 365.25) AS years,
  FLOOR(MOD(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), dob), 365.25) / (365.25 / 12)) AS months
FROM age
```