# How to determine the difference between two dates in years and months in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

The database holds records for people of all ages including children under the age of 1 where months are important.

Using

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE()) AS age;
```

The problem you get is anyone < 1 year shows up as 0;

Using

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, dob, CURDATE()) AS age;
```

Anyone over the age of 1 just shows up in months so a 43 year old will have an age of > 500 months

Using

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, dob, CURDATE()) / 12 AS age;
```

You can get some results like .25 for a 3 month old or 43.25 for someone who is > 43

What I am trying to achieve is something like

- 43y 3m
- 0y 3m
- or even just 3m for those < 1 year

How can something like this be expressed in a mysql query?

Comment: Maybe this answers your question : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18181808/3617573

Comment: Thanks @AlexandreFILLATRE That question was oddly phrased it didn't come up in my search

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, dob, CURDATE())>12,TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, dob, CURDATE())/12+ 'yeasrs old' , TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, dob, CURDATE())+'months old')
```